# How can I remove my work history in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

If I worked in word, excel or some other software is it possible after my work to remove all history of opened file and all changes that I made without any extra software?

Comment: I think this question belongs in SuperUser.com  ....

Comment: Don't forget about last modified date, and if on a shared folder, the username/computer that made the change.

Comment: Haha yeah, "work history".

Answer (score 1):

All tracks?, no you would need other software, you can delete your recent history though.

Older versions of Office
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313454

2007, 2010
http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeprog/thread/0a248806-d385-4ef6-ba65-0739ae515aba

Answer (score 0):

try: right click system drive(in my computer) you are looking for "disk clean-up". you can remove all temporary files, internethistory, not sure if this removes "recent history" but you could try

Answer (score 0):

Try **[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/)**, it cleans up multiple programs, etc for temporary files, viewed webpages, history, and the like.